# How to pass Session and Request dependencies to MVC Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Action that is using the Request and Session objects.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {            
            string eventTypeId = Request.QueryString[QueryStringFor.EventTypeId];

            Session["eventTypeId"] = eventTypeId; 

            return View();
        }
```

How to make this action unit testable?

Should I be passing and injecting those when controllers are initialized?

I'm using ControllerBuilder to build my controllers manually (not using IOC at the moment)

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new DefaultControllerFactory(new EvaluationCompositionRoot()));

 public class EvaluationCompositionRoot : IControllerActivator
    {
        public IController Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
```

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net mvc, the Request and Session **are already objects of classes deriving from [HttpRequestBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [HttpSessionStateBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpsessionstatebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** respectively. There should not be problems mocking these objects during unit-testing

Comment: I understand what you mean in terms of the testing. How to pass the Session and Request to the Controllers for the production code? HttpContext or something?

Comment: @The Light: asp.net mvc already does that for you. You want to build a custom one?

Comment: You're right but if I make them must injectables then... I mean after mocking these objects in my unit tests, I'd like to pass them to my Controller. I can pass them using constructor injection for my tests but then how to pass it for the product codes.

Comment: @The Light: Production code should do it similarly with unit-test code. But in production code, these information is retrieved based on the current httpcontext.

Comment: @The Light: I think you should use the DefaultControllerFactory of the asp.net mvc framework. If you need to extend the framework to add DI capability, you could try implement IDependencyResolver and register it with the framework http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver